# Grails i18n UrlMappings

Tags: grails, internationalization

I am dealing with the following problem. In our project we have launched different internationalized domains for the same website.
The problem comes with the UrlMappings for the different languages.
for example:

- English: name contact: "/contact"(controller: 'static', action: 'index') { id = '/contact' }
- German: name deContact: "/kontakt"(controller: 'static', action: 'index') { id = '/contact' }

repeating all the code again and again. Is there a solution to group both url mappings to use the same controller, action and logic ?

for example it would be nice to have something similar like this: 
name contact: "[/contact|/kontakt/etc..]"(controller: 'static', action: 'index') { id = '/contact' }
Giving optional urls that calls the same code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLMapping block is a dsl, but you can use Groovy inside of it.

You could do something like:

```
['contact', 'kontact'].each{
    "/${it}"( view: "/blah")
}
```

which does create the routings you are asking for. This example is pretty simplistic, but you could potentially hook into things like the i18n message bundles to do something like

```
getKeysFor( 'contact' ).each{
    ... your mapping here
}
```

it feels like this is something that your controller should be handling, since the i18n support is likely to be better there than at the url mapping level.

I am pretty sure this would break your ability to use named url mappings though.

Answer (score 4):

You can have the `UrlMapping` read the mapping name from the `messageSource` per `Locale` and use the same in the mapping. Something like:

**UrlMapping.groovy**

```
    import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder as LCH
    class UrlMappings {
        static mappings = {
            def i18nContact = getGrailsApplication().getMainContext().getMessage('app.url.mapping.contact', [] as Object[], 'contact', LCH.getLocale())

            "/${i18nContact}"(controller: 'static', action: 'index') { id = '/contact' }
        }
    }
```

**messages.properties**

app.url.mapping.contact=contact

**messages_de.properties**

app.url.mapping.contact=kontakt

You just need to keep on adding the entries for other `locales` in the corresponding message source.

**Note:**
You can test the same by setting to default `Locale` to GERMANY in the `resources.groovy` as

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.FixedLocaleResolver
beans = {
    localeResolver(FixedLocaleResolver, Locale.GERMANY) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMANY)
    }
}
```

Comment: No I don't think so since we are reading from `messageSource` and not involved in any `transactional` activity (or `database` trips). But you can very well load test the same in your functional tests. Please feel free to provide your feedback, up/down votes, accept/decline the answer if it is fit/unfit to your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a similar solution but at least for me an easier one. Basically the idea would be to have the mapping names in messages.properties

**messages.properties**

```
app.url.mapping.contact = enContact
```

**messages_es.properties**

```
app.url.mapping.contact = esContact
```

Then we can have this UrlMappings configuration

```
static mappings = {
    name enContact: "/contact"(view:"/static/contact")
    name esContact: "/contacto"(view:"/static/contact")
}
```

And finally in the views you can use the mapping attribute in this way:

```
<g:link mapping="${g.message(code:'app.url.mapping.contact', default:'enContact')}">
    <g:message code="contact" default="Contact"/>
</g:link>
```