# How to get Locale in UrlMappings

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I am trying to get the Locale in UrlMappings to have unilingual Urls in the language chosen by the user.

I have tried the following (similar to what is suggested in [Grails i18n UrlMappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362408/grails-i18n-urlmappings))

```
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder as LCH

class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {   
        def myLocale = LCH.getLocale()
        if (myLocale == 'fr') {
            "/francais"(controller:'foo', action:'index')
        }
        else if (myLocale == 'en') {
            "/english"(controller:'foo', action:'index')
        } 
    }

}
```

My variable doesn't seem to be set correctly. If I add the getLocale() method in my index.gsp or in my error page, the value is displayed correctly.

It the locale accessible in UrlMappings?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Does `myLocale` have a value, just not the correct one?

Comment: @dpcasady  Thanks for taking the time to comment. When I do it as indicated in my initial example, it seems like there is no value for myLocale. But I tried doing `LCH.getLocale().getLanguage()` instead and in that case, it seems to be 'en' all the time. Thinking it's taking the default Locale and not the chosen one?

Comment: @NBabineau . Did u got the solution?